# One PHP Library for many social networking sites' authorization?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

I know there are many libraries out there for OAuth and for specific sites' authentication and authorization. I'm wondering, is there any one-stop-shopping library that easily, robustly and perhaps modularly integrates with many popular social networking sites?

It would be nice to have a single library, which, given a set of IDs (FB, twitter, foursquare, etc...) would manage authorization (and maybe sessions in the case of things like FBConnect) for all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm experimenting with HybridAuth at the moment : http://sourceforge.net/projects/hybridauth/
Its progressing along very well and can interface with many of the public apis out there.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as well, it seems that this library is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered integrating OpenID into your site?

http://openid.net/developers/libraries/#php

Comment: Yes, but given its limited penetration and slow growth I don't think it's a replacement yet - just one more thing that might be supported by the library I'm looking for.